# Robotframework: Getting date at runtime using Get Current Date, in specific format

Tags: date, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, robotframework

I am using the [Get Current Date](http://rfdocs.org/browse/robot-2.8.5/datetime/Get%20Current%20Date/) keyword to return the date in the format year-month-day. I use this particular information to make sure that an account's *created* timestamp is correct in automated tests.

The issue is that the keyword is not recognised, my code should be correct (it should work **and** it should produce the date in the format I wish.

```
*** Keywords ***

Initialize Test Data
    ${DATE}=    Get Current Date    result_format=timestamp
    ${MYNUM}=    faker.Random Int

    Set Suite Variable  ${MYNUM}
    Set Suite Variable  ${DATE}
```

Why do I get the error `No keyword with name 'Get Current Date' found.`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does a keyword **Get Current Date** exist in standard RF lib? There is a builtin keyword called **[Get Time](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/3.0.2/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Time)** instead. Documentation explains how to format output. To use **Get Current Date** you need to import **DateTime** library first.

Update:
RF script sample which works for me:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           DateTime

*** Test Cases ***
datatimetest
   ${d}=    get time
   log    {d}
   ${d}=    Get Current Date    result_format=%Y-%m-%d
   log    {d}
   ${d} =    Add Time To Date    2014-05-28 12:05:03.111    7 days
   log    {d}
```

Please remember that DateTime is a new library so in case you have old version of Robot Framework, you need to either install library or upgrade RF.

Comment: If you look at the link for Get Current Date it does it exist, and I am using that specific version of RF..

Never the less, if I wanted to use `Get Time` how could I truncate the output so that I have date-month-day ?

Comment: Yes, I realized that after I posted the answer. However it is not builtin keyword. You need to import DateTime library. I've updated my answer already.

Comment: According to the documentation the output of `${DATE}= DateTime.Get Current Date result_format=timestamp` should be (for today at least) _2014-07-23_, correct?

Comment: I don't think you need "DateTime." before your keyword. I'm adding RF script sample to my answer.

Comment: Thank you.

I have DateTime. as a prefix because I am using the library with name "DateTime" for documentation/learning purposes when my collegues look at this.

Comment: I'm afraid that your test script doesn't give me the data in the format I want. Each of your three called keywords produce their result in the same format, I want my data to be returned in the format "year-month-day"

Comment: I thought this question was about keyword not being recognised. Anyway, I've edited answer once again, now it contains result formating. It should finally work.

Comment: My second paragraph says that what my code should produce (in my eyes) as well as that it should be working :p

Never the less, I had just worked out that I could specify the actual format. I'll select your answer now, thank you!

Comment: I tried above mentioned answer, but it not showing me current date. thought it is not giving any error too. I installed DateTime library in settings

Answer (score 1):

I'm using RF with Python and by default my IDE detects Python DateTime library.
Try to use the full path:

```
Library           robot.libraries.DateTime
```

[robot.libraries.DateTime](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.org/en/2.9.2/_modules/robot/libraries/DateTime.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also format the time as you like.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254674/robotframework-get-current-date).  It offers format suggestions.  You can use Python DateTime functions as in

```
   ${now}    Evaluate    '{dt.day}/{dt.month}/{dt.year}'.format(dt=datetime.datetime.now())    modules=datetime
   Log   ${now}
   Log to Console   now time 1: ${now}
   ${now}    Evaluate  '{dt:%A}, {dt:%B} {dt.day}, {dt.year}'.format(dt=datetime.datetime.now())    modules=datetime
   Log   ${now}
   Log to Console   now time 2: ${now}
```