# RobotFramework - get current Date

Tags: date, format, robotframework

I need to test that the current date is displayed on my device, The date on the device is in format `Monday, September 9, 2018` but when i try to test it i can only use the format `Monday, 09, 2018` which would fail the test as there is no 0 in the Month date.

```
    page should contain element  ${DATE}
    ${DATE_MESSAGE}  get current date  result_format=%A, %d, %Y
    element should contain text  ${DATE}  ${DATE_MESSAGE}
```

How can change the format in robotframework to verify THis format `Monday, September 9, 2018.`

**ERROR** `should have contained text 'Monday, 09, 2018' but its text was 'Monday, September 9, 2018'.`

Comment: Which format you want ? your question seem so blur

Comment: @SidaraKEO i have update the question sorry for the misuderstaing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
${now}    Evaluate    '{dt.day}/{dt.month}/{dt.year}'.format(dt=datetime.datetime.now())    modules=datetime
```

After update:

```
${now}    Evaluate  '{dt:%A}, {dt:%B} {dt.day}, {dt.year}'.format(dt=datetime.datetime.now())    modules=datetime
```

Comment: Sorry I have missphrased my question i have added the fail message and updated the question

Comment: `'Monday, 9, 2018' but its text was 'Monday, September 10, 2018'.`
i am getting this error

Answer (score 5):

This can be done much more easy

${date}=         Get Current Date         UTC        exclude_millis=yes
${convert}=      Convert Date         ${date}         result_format=%a %B %d %H:%M:%S UTC %Y
Log        ${convert}       console=yes

(%a = f.e. Mon
 %A = f.e. Monday
 %B = f.e. May
 %H:%M:%S - f.e.   13:04:09
 UTC = f.e. part of string needed
 %Y = 2019)

The output on the console of the string above will give:

Fri May 10 10:12:31 UTC 2019

If you want to add certain amount of days use:

${date}=         Get Current Date        UTC        exclude_millis=yes
${plus14}=         Add Time To Date        ${date}         14 days 
${future}         Convert Date         ${plus14}         result_format=%a %B %d %H:%M:%S UTC %Y
Log         ${future}           console=yes

The output will be:

Fri May 24 10:12:31 UTC 2019

Comment: See [how to format code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), you don't have to put all those `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 1):

Robot Framework has an extensive DateTime library built-in (since version 2.8.5).

If you are able to import that library, documented here ( http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html ).  You should be able to use the Get Current Date keyword.

This keyword has a parameter that allows you to use Python's date formation format to get the date/time format you need.